# Problems working with the dates of this dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        REGION  YEAR  WEEK ILITOTAL TOTAL_PATIENTS
0      Alabama  2010    40      249          11664
52     Alabama  2010    41      239          11602
104    Alabama  2010    42      232          11945
156    Alabama  2010    43      274          12036
208    Alabama  2010    44      342          12069
...        ...   ...   ...      ...            ...
22688  Alabama  2018    48     1263          41155
22742  Alabama  2018    49     1152          38716
22796  Alabama  2018    50     1420          38703
22850  Alabama  2018    51     1585          38533
22904  Alabama  2018    52     1977          38097
```

And the fact that it does not have dates in a YYYY/MM/DD format is giving me some trouble, mostly at plotting stuff. For example, in this case, I want to end up with a plot more or less like this:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnlUe.png)

To do so, I just left the YEAR, WEEK, and TOTAL_PATIENTS and I have tried to combine the WEEK and YEAR columns,

```
Sdf_copy["WEEK_YEAR"] = Sdf_copy.WEEK.astype(str).str.cat(Sdf_copy.YEAR.astype(str), sep="-")

Sdf_AL = Sdf_copy[['WEEK_YEAR', 'TOTAL_PATIENTS']].copy()
print(Sdf_AL)
```

ending up with this:

```
      WEEK_YEAR TOTAL_PATIENTS
0       40-2010          11664
52      41-2010          11602
104     42-2010          11945
156     43-2010          12036
208     44-2010          12069
...         ...            ...
22688   48-2018          41155
22742   49-2018          38716
22796   50-2018          38703
22850   51-2018          38533
22904   52-2018          38097
```

I have tried plotting this in different ways, a simple plot

```
plt.plot(Sdf_AL)
plt.show()
```

gives this error: *TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'*
and with something like this

```
plt.plot(Sdf_AL.TOTAL_PATIENTS)
plt.show()
```

or

```
plt.plot(Sdf_AL.WEEK_YEAR, Sdf_AL.TOTAL_PATIENTS)
plt.show()
```

it always turns out similar to this:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc7Tu.png)

any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When dealing with weekly data, it's useful to be aware of a quirk: some weekly data uses the [ISO week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), which is unusual because it handles the beginning of a year as part of the previous year, to avoid splitting weeks across years.  @tyson.wu's solution is good if you have non-ISO weeks.

Comment: The thing is that I am using this dataframe for forecasting so the original dataframe column distribution works fine for me, but for plotting is giving me problems

Comment: Got it - the most common problem when plotting a dataset like this is that one of your columns is in string format. When a column is in string format, Pandas will label every single point, because it doesn't know which ones it can omit. If you convert the column to a datetime, then you'll be able to plot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts of issues here:
(1) You are getting troubles with dates that has no specific day
(2) You are not able to plot correctly.

Addressing (1):
The most convenient way is to hard code the week start as the day, and convert it into datetime object for the ease of plotting:

```
Sdf_AL['WEEK_YEAR'] = pd.to_datetime(Sdf_AL['WEEK_YEAR']+'-1', format='%W-%Y-%w')
```

The `+'-1'` here is to hard code a weekday number to the column `WEEK_YEAR`, so that the `WEEK_YEAR` would look like eg. 40-2010-1 in format of Week-Year-Weekday (before converting into datetime).

Addressing (2):
In `plt.plot(Sdf_AL.TOTAL_PATIENTS)` you did not explicitly specify the x-axis and y-axis of the plot. Hence the plot automatically renders with the index as the x-axis. In your case, the indices in the `Sdf_AL` is something like [0, 52, 104, 156, 208, ...] hence the weird plot render.

You should explicitly specify the axes. Try

```
plt.plot(Sdf_AL.WEEK_YEAR, Sdf_AL.TOTAL_PATIENTS)
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your comment. I've tried what you said. 
`plt.plot(Sdf_AL.WEEK_YEAR, Sdf_AL.TOTAL_PATIENTS)` gives the same result as  `plt.plot(Sdf_AL.TOTAL_PATIENTS)` but the x axis gets worse https://gyazo.com/89ad679231bbc317381eaa92c1ce1394.

I saw that `pd.to_datetime` was useful, but didn't think about hard coding a day. So, I have tried what you said and it looks like it detects that 40 is not a viable week number and adapts 40-2010 to 2010-10-04 instead of 40-2010-1, and the plot turns out:
https://gyazo.com/aa2f1fc5e415f0dff60f5ef6a418b4ef

Comment: @JavierdeDiosG. I think 40-2010-1 really does correspond to a date of 2010-10-04. If you run `pd.to_datetime("39-2010-1", format='%W-%Y-%w')` you get 2010-09-27, which is a week before that.

Comment: Tyson, I'd suggest using the `df.plot()` shortcut for plotting the data. e.g. `Sdf_AL.plot(x='WEEK_YEAR', y='TOTAL_PATIENTS')`. [More information](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/04_plotting.html)

Comment: There is also an additional issue that I suspect, where the `TOTAL_PATIENTS` column is not of type 'int'. Try `Sdf_AL['TOTAL_PATIENTS'] = Sdf_AL['TOTAL_PATIENTS'].astype(int)` and see if it solves the y-axis problem.

Comment: That was it, TOTAL_PATIENTS was a type object, by doing everything you guys said in these comments now the plot makes much more sense and seems correct.
https://gyazo.com/afb7dad8970048a5b87e7d31ae4cc491
Thank you guys!